# Updated Android_HOME variable Ionic Issue

Tags: android, ionic-framework, build.gradle

There is an issue with the path. Android Studio SDK is present in my D drive. When I execute the build command I get the following error
"Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
Looked here: C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\templates\gradle\wrapper"

Actual SDK location is in 
"D:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\templates\gradle\wrapper". What should I change in Ionic app such that it looks for SDK in D drive?

Here is the Log

```
C:\Users\Max\Desktop\Gre\demo\demoApp>ionic build android
```

Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\Max\Desktop\Gre\demo\demoApp\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js C:\Users\Max\Desktop\Gre\demo\demoApp

add to body class: platform-android

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_121

Subproject Path: CordovaLib

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\Max\Desktop\Gre\demo\demoApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 64
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

  > No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Home to update the ANDROID_HOME variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get just the command line tools here : https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads

Next unzip, copy/paste 'templates' folder in '.../Android/sdk/tools/'

Answer (score 1):

Unzip -> copy and paste "tools" >only "templates" folder to your project folder (/Libraries/Android/sdk/tools/)

Example: C:\Users\yourUsers\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools

Link http://tools.android.com/recent/androidsdktoolsrevision2530feb2017